# Azure Data Factory Dataflow trouble with ToDecimal

Tags: azure, expression, decimal, factory, dataflow

Im kinda new with ADF so thats why im struggling with the following task:

My source file is a csv file and  has a column TotalCost and TotalSales. These columns has a string type. In My destionation sql table i would like to change this to a decimal type. This is the expected output in the destination table.

[image]

When i use the Dataflow task Derived Column, i use the Expression builder in order to change the type String to Decimal.

In the expression builder i used the **toDecimal (TotalCost**).

After running the dataflow in ADF i get the following result in the destination table:

[image]

As you can see NULL values are returned because some records from picture 1 has a decimal value.

i assumed that toDecimal (TotalCost) is not the right expression. Any suggestion? Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar kind of issue with decimal conversion.

toDecimal() function considers precision as decimal(10,2) by default. What I did was altered the precision as below :

**toDecimal(YourColumnName,20,4)**

to be used in derived columns and that did my work. I hope this helps you!